# How restore a Heroku PG database on a MAC

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I created a .dump on Heroku and dowloaded it.

Using pgAdmin4, I created a new table and tried to restore using the Heroku downloaded dump file.

I get the message "pg_restore:[archiver] unsupported version (1.13) in file header.

My pg_restore version is 9.1.13

Comment: I also installed PG on a new MAC using HomeBrew.  It installed v 10.3.  I then tried to restore the Heroku db and got the same message.

Comment: How do I get the CVE-2018-1058 patch installed? Will that fix it?

Comment: It sounds like you've successfully upgraded Postgres, but there's another step to actually upgrade the database: `brew postgresql-upgrade-database`. Note that you should back up your local databases before running that command if you have critical data on them. I also recommend reading this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49064209/getting-archiver-unsupported-version-1-13-in-file-header-when-running-pg-r

Comment: I used the brew command and got: Error: postgresql data already upgraded!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that pgAdmin4 uses it's own old copy of pg_restore in the application contents.  I used my system pg_restore on the command line and it worked.