# How to restore PostgreSQL database from dump file

Tags: database, postgresql, backup

I am trying to restore the backup file to PostgreSQL DB by;

`pg_restore -d db_name -U user_name -C backup.dmp`

However, I get this error when I executed this command.

```
pg_restore: [archiver] unsupported version (1.14) in file header
```

The version of the PostgreSQL DB I'm using is `11.6 (Ubuntu 11.6-1.pgdg18.04+1)`

I assumed I need to upgrade PostgreSQL DB so I tried this command on the server.

```
brew upgrade postgresql
```

However, I get this error this time..

```
Error: postgresql not installed
```

I would appreciate any help or advice. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: How did you generate the backup?

Comment: I made the backup file using 
`pg_dump --host=host_name --dbname=db_name --username=user_name --password=password --format=c --file=backup.dmp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to work with a dump file that was created on a Mac, and you are trying to restore it on another machine (or the other way around?).  `brew` is a Mac package manager.  The equivalent for Ubuntu is `apt`.  To install Postgres on Ubuntu, please follow the [steps on the Ubuntu page of the PostgreSQL website](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/).  To upgrade, you should be able to do `apt-get upgrade`.

You may also not be able to `brew upgrade postgresql` on your Mac because Postgres may have been installed in another way (you may want to use Spotlight to find out whether your `pg_dump` lives in some `.../Cellar/...` folder or a `.../Postgres.app/...` folder (or some other folder), and perform your upgrade accordingly.

In either case, it seems you are encountering this archiver error message because of a [missing security patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49064209/getting-archiver-unsupported-version-1-13-in-file-header-when-running-pg-r)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I saw the guy asked similar question here and answer was using so I was using it blindly.. I made dump file on Ubuntu and also try to restore it on Ubuntu. I managed to get upgrade with apt-get and now I get this error.
`pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "data" already exists`
It seems file header error is gone at least :)

Comment: Great! Your current error means that there is already a `data` table in your database. You need to either rename it or drop it before attempting to restore the dump